# 64 bit support for react native @0.55.4?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

how can we add 64bit support for react-native android application in react-native version 0.55.4?

I am currently in 0.55.4 and play store is giving error of 64bit support.

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept and vote up an answer for further references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React native supports 64bit since [0.59.0](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.59.0) so I recommend to upgrade to this version

> You can use [this link](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.55.4&to=0.59.10) for an easy upgrade!

Please consider upgrading to 0.59.10 since the early 0.59 versions are buggy!

Comment: i've upgraded but not react-navigation tabnavigator (changing tabs on press) is not working. using "react-navigation": "^1.1.0-rc.2",

Comment: Then i also recommend to upgrade react-navigation v3